# Calling a Java Method from the native code using jni

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am new at using JNI. I successfully write a few programs that call native methods written in c.

Now I need my java code to be called by the native code side after it is initialized. Is it possible?
Until now, I tried some kind of polling techniques. That is, I check native code parameters from my java code periodically, but if there is a way that native code can send some kind of interrupt it could be more efficient. Is it possible? Or can you suggest a better way than polling?

Note:
 When I search for "Call Java Functions from C Using JNI" all the answers I get is like

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22881/How-to-Call-Java-Functions-from-C-Using-JNI

[JNI Call java method from c program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955584/jni-call-java-method-from-c-program)

Those examples is not an answer for my situation. Because my main program is in java, and what I ask is that: Can the native functions(written in c) that I call from java code call some other java functions under certain circumstances? Is it possible to manage this without using a polling technique like I mentioned above?

Comment: Just synchronously should be very easy, i.e. Java calls a C function which calls a Java function and returns and returns. (What's tricker is if your C function is setting up a background thread which independently calls Java functions at random points in time.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sure. It is actually easier than in the examples you linked because you don't have to spawn a JVM to do it -- the java functions that call you give you a pointer to the environment that you can use. As a simple example: With a Java class like this:

```
public class foo {
  static {
    // load libfoo.so / foo.dll
    System.loadLibrary("foo");
  }

  private native void nativecall();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo f = new foo();

    f.nativecall();
  }

  public void callback() {
    System.out.println("callback");
  }

  public static void callback_static() {
    System.out.println("static callback");
  }
}
```

And a library compiled from C code like this:

```
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_foo_nativecall(JNIEnv *env, jobject foo_obj) {
  // Get the class from the object we got passed in
  jclass cls_foo = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, foo_obj);

  // get the method IDs from that class
  jmethodID mid_callback        = (*env)->GetMethodID      (env, cls_foo, "callback"       , "()V");
  jmethodID mid_callback_static = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls_foo, "callback_static", "()V");

  // then call them.
  (*env)->CallVoidMethod      (env, foo_obj, mid_callback);
  (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, cls_foo, mid_callback_static);
}
```

you would get the output

```
callback
static callback
```

If you don't get an object of the class you want to work with, you can use the `FindClass` and `NewObject` functions to make one, as in

```
jclass    cls_foo  = (*env)->FindClass  (env, "foo");
jmethodID ctor_foo = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls_foo, "<init>", "()V");
jobject   foo_obj  = (*env)->NewObject  (env, cls_foo, ctor_foo);
```

Further reading [here](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html).

Comment: works inside a native call. link is dead